# Force GIF image reload in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to reload a GIF image (`CHECKMARK_ANIMATION_ICON` is the source) to start the gif animation every 12 seconds or every time the `activeIndex` is changing.

This is my code:

```
   const reloadImgSource = (imgSource) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
       setImgSource("");
       setImgSource(imgSource);
      }, 1);
   };

  const handleActiveDot = (index, item) => {
    setActiveIndex(index);
    setActiveTopBonus(item);
    reloadImgSource(CHECKMARK_ANIMATION_ICON);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const activeIndexInterval = setInterval(() => {
      reloadImgSource(CHECKMARK_ANIMATION_ICON);
      if (topBonusList && activeIndex !== topBonusList.length - 1) {
        setActiveIndex(activeIndex + 1);
      } else {
        setActiveIndex(0);
      }
    }, 12000);

    return () => clearInterval(activeIndexInterval);

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [activeIndex, topBonusList]);
```

```
<img src={`${imgSource}`} alt="Checkmark Icon" />
```

This code is working but I think the solution in `reloadImgSource` is a workaround.
I used setTimeout set to `1`  because otherwise the animation is not triggered as the source is not set to an empty string and then back to the original value to retrigger the GIF.

Is there a better solution I can implement for `reloadImgSource` that allows me to trigger the load of the GIF when the function is fired?

Note that I cannot use hash in the image source as the gif will not be cached and this is a problem for me

Comment: Better idea: convert the GIF into an MP4, then load that into a `<video>` element. That way you can use the playback API.

Comment: You could probably switch out the `setTimeout` for `requestAnimationFrame`, but you will need _something_ of this sort, otherwise the rendering engine will not "notice" any change in the image src attribute to begin with. GIF animations are notoriously hard to "control", that's why all the social network platforms usually replace any user-uploaded GIF content with a video. For any animated icons within your app, I would probably rather use SVG these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I arrived at this better solution to remove the workaround with `setTimeout`, the result is the same but the code is more clean and readable, and avoids all caching issues:

```
  const [imgSource, setImgSource] = useState(ANIMATION_ICON);

  const reloadImgSource = async (imgSource) => {
    setImgSource(imgSource);
  };

  const animationTrigger = async () => {
    await reloadImgSource("");
    await reloadImgSource(ANIMATION_ICON);
  };

  const handleActiveDot = (index, item) => {
    setActiveIndex(index);
    setActiveTopBonus(item);
    animationTrigger();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const activeIndexInterval = setInterval(() => {
      animationTrigger();
      if (topBonusList && activeIndex !== topBonusList.length - 1) {
        setActiveIndex(activeIndex + 1);
      } else {
        setActiveIndex(0);
      }
    }, 12000);

    return () => clearInterval(activeIndexInterval);

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [activeIndex, topBonusList]);
```

```
<img src={imgSource} alt="Animation Icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way how you can do that

```js
function App() {
  const [activeInbox, setActiveInbox] = useState(0);
  const [animation, setAnimation] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAnimation(true);
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setAnimation(false);
    }, 1200);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [activeInbox]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {animation && (
        <img
          src={`https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/315048/screenshots/3710002/check.gif?${activeInbox}`}
        />
      )}
      <button onClick={() => setActiveInbox((i) => i + 1)}>
        Change active inbox
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But I'd suggest avoiding such kind of implementations because the gif won't be cached properly, and the client will load a new gif every inbox update. If you can use another kind of animation, look at SVG.

Comment: I already tried this implementation, and I do not want to use an hash on the source as I wrote in the question because of major caching issues

Comment: _"and the client will load a new gif every inbox update."_ - you can avoid that by loading the GIF into an `URL.createObjectURL()` and using that to reset the image element, that way the browser won't make a new HTTP request for it.

Comment: @Dai Unfortunately it won't be a simple solution as well. It requires specific CORS headers.

Comment: @ValentinKutin What CORS issues? `createObjectURL` is considered same-origin by browsers.

Comment: @Dai yes, but there is no any guarantee the gif will be shared by the same origin. And if try to get a blob via a http request, it might be rejected by CORS policy.

Comment: @ValentinKutin `GET` requests generally don't cause CORS issues either - but even if the remote-host was tightly locked-down then it's trivial to spin up one's own reverse-proxy to get it for us.

Comment: Potentially it might create another issue.

So, @giosan I'd still recommend to find another solution. mp4 should be much better

Comment: @Dai We are talking about proxy for one single gif? I didn't tell it's impossible, I mean the cost is much higher than the initial task. It might solved by much simpler way. Proposed by you mp4 idea is much better.

Comment: @ValentinKutin If you're feeling up to it, I think there's a WASM port of `ffmpeg` - so you *could* download hundreds of MB of WASM to convert that GIF into an in-memory MP4 all in JavaScript :)

Answer (score 0):

useState hook doesn't change state immediately line by line, but it schedule updating state, it is the reason the first setImgSource which tries to empty imgSource will be ignored.

try:

```
const reloadImgSource = (imgSource) => {       
   setImgSource("");
   setTimeout(() => {
       setImgSource(imgSource);
   }, 1);
};
```

Comment: yes but I'm asking if there is an alternative solution to this workaround, I was aware of this that's why I used ```setTimeout``` in the original code, that already works